# Best way to move data between tables in MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a question regarding performance. This is my scenario.

I have a MYSQL database and a application that from time to time moves records, according to the criteria from a query, from one table to another. The way this is done is:

```
foreach(object obj in list)
{
    string id = obj.ToString().Split(',')[0].Trim();
    string query = " insert into old_records select * from testes where id='" + 
                    id + "';" + " delete from testes where id='" + id +"'";

    DB _db = new DB();
    _db.DBConnect(query);
```

this is the way I connect to the database:

```
DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
MySqlConnection _conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand _cmd = new MySqlCommand
{
    Connection = _conn,
    CommandText = query
};
MySqlDataAdapter _da = new MySqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
MySqlCommandBuilder _cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(_da);

_dt.Clear();

try
{
    _conn.Open();
    _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    _da.Fill(_dt);
}

catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

finally
{
    if (_conn != null) _conn.Close();
}
return _dt;
```

So my question is, I have like 4000 rows in the table, and it takes a lot of time to move all the records from one table to another, specially across a network. Is there a way to make this faster?

I have been doing some reading and there are several option to handle data from DB like data adapters, reader, set, and tables. Which one is faster for this case? Should I be using a different method?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see is that first you're opening and closing your connection for each insert, that's usually your most expensive operation so you won't want to do that.  You can also try batching them rather than doing them at once.  When you do that you have to be careful because things could break in the middle of a large update so you would want to do things in a transaction.  Without knowing too much about what your data structure looks like I refactored your method to do batching 100 at a time.  First create a little helper method called move items that takes a connection and a list of ids.  Don't do a try catch in this, you'll see why later.

**Note:** This method doesn't use parameters, I highly recommend you change it to do that.

```
private static void MoveItems(MySqlConnection conn, List<string> moveList)
{
    string query = string.Format("insert into old_records select * from testes where id IN({0});" + " delete from testes where id IN({0})", string.Join(",", moveList.ToArray()));

    var cmd = new MySqlCommand
    {
        Connection = conn,
        CommandText = query
    };

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Next you'll change your main method to open the database connection once and then call this method 100 id's at a time.  This method will have a try catch therefore if the call to MoveItems throws an exception it will be caught in this main method.

```
// the using statement will call your dispose method
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // open the connection and start the transaction
    conn.Open();
    var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

    // createa  list to temporarily store the ids
    List<string> moves = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        // clean the list, do the trim and get everything that's not null or empty
        var cleanList = list.Select(obj => obj.ToString().Split(',')[0].Trim()).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));

        // loop over the clean list
        foreach (string id in cleanList)
        {
            // add the id to the move list
            moves.Add("'" + id + "'");

            // batch 100 at a time
            if (moves.Count % 100 == 0)
            {
                // when I reach 100 execute them and clear the list out
                MoveItems(conn, moves);
                moves.Clear();
            }
        }

        // The list count might not be n (mod 100) therefore see if there's anything left
        if (moves.Count > 0)
        {
            MoveItems(conn, moves);
            moves.Clear();
        }

        // wohoo! commit the transaction
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        // oops!  something happened roll back everything
        transaction.Rollback();
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

You may have to play with that 100 number.  I remember when I worked with MySQL a lot I saw some performance differences between doing an IN and giving it a list of Or statements (Id = 'ID1' OR id = 'ID2' ...).  But executing 40 statements or 80 statements will certainly have better performance, and opening the database connection once instead of 4000 times should also give you much better performance.

Answer (score -1):

I might be wrong, but there is not much you can do in order to make it faster. After all you want to get the entire table data and insert its information into another table. The process **will** take some time if your table isn't small. However, you can try using the code below. It should do the trick and save some time.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (FIELDNAME_IN_TABLE2, FIELDNAME2_IN_TABLE2)
SELECT FIELDNAME_IN_TABLE1, FIELDNAME2_IN_TABLE1
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: will this move ? By moving, insert to new and delete from old ?

Comment: It should move the data from table one to another, however it does not delete any records.

Comment: Your first point is correct, but your code will only work if the database are on the same server. You would need to link the servers if it was over the network.

Comment: @gunr2171 I have this already runing across the network.. each record takes about 2 seconds :( imagine 4000 !

Comment: @TommyNaidich but i also need to delete from the first when it's copied to the second... I need to move not copy.